# Android NDK build issue - jni flac

Tags: android

I've gone through the Android hello-jni tutorial and had it able to build.  I'm now trying to run the ndk-build within my workspace area.

```
=======================
MobileApp/jni/flac
$ ../../../../../android-ndk-r8d-windows/ndk/ndk-build
make: Nothing to be done for `cd'.
=======================
```

Tried from project directory root

```
=======================
MobileApp/
$ ../../../android-ndk-r8d-windows/ndk/ndk-build
make: Nothing to be done for `cd'.
=======================
```

If I do a google search I don't seem to see these 'cd' error, only 'all'.  I'm using cygwin.  Do I need to be modifying the AndroidManifest.xml after I add the jni/flac directory?

I've tried adding this (like in the hello-jni example), but there was no change in the error msg.

```
=================
        <activity android:name=".flac"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
================
```

Do you guys/gals need to review the andriod.mk file?
On a side note, the app project that I'm using was taken from Ubuntu and brought to windows. I didn't think that would do anything, but I'm mentioning it just to be safe.

Mike